# Как сделать так, чтобы эллипс двигался в пределе прямоугольника?

Tags: c#, uwp, графика, рисование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
XAML
<Grid Background="LightBlue">


        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle Name="rec" Height="60" Width="200" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Left="550" Canvas.Top="220" >

            </Rectangle>
            <Ellipse Name="ell" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Red"  ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="ell_ManipulationDelta"  Canvas.Left="552" Canvas.Top="223"  >
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="trans"/>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>


C#
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ell_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           trans.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо чтоб эллипс не выходил за приделы прямоугольника, надо чтоб это работал как некий переключатель(в дальнейшем).

Comment: В UWP уже есть такой же самый переключатель. Правильнее будет изменить его стиль/шаблон. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/toggles

Comment: Надо свой сделать

Comment: Надо и то и другое, но меня больше интересует функционал

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил сам ответил. Надо задать координаты прямоугольника и использовать не Delta а MouseDown MouseDrag MouseUp
Вот код решения 
C# 
namespace SwitchButton
{
    public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    bool Action = false;

    double InitPxls = 15;
    double FinitePxls = 420;
    double Movement;

    Point Point;

    private void ell_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Action = true;
        Point = Mouse.GetPosition(ell);
        Mouse.Capture(ell);
    }

    private void ell_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Action)
        {
            Movement = Canvas.GetLeft(ell) + Mouse.GetPosition(ell).X - Point.X;

            if (Movement > InitPxls && Movement < FinitePxls)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(ell, Movement);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ell_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Action = false;
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
}
```